# Swift : Animate width and height of UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, animatewithduration

Inside of these two functions, I want to animate the button shrinking(gone), then animate it growing(seen). I was able to animate it growing, but not at first have the button shrink. Any help on how to animate a button shrinking?

```
func progressBarButtonFadeOut(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
    //timeCapDesign is a UIButton
        self.timeCapDesign.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0)

    })
}

//Progress Bar Fade In Buttons
func progressBarButtonFadeIn(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {

        self.timeCapDesign.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

    })
}
```

Comment: Do you have more context / sample code on how you setup and use this ?

Comment: The timeCapDesign button is on the screen, when a user selects a different button, it will call "progressBarButtonFadeOut()" and the timeCapDesign button will shrink until its gone,  and then after if the user selects a different button it will call "progressBarButtonFadeIn()" and the timeCapDesign button will grow in. @LudovicLandry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got it. So what i had to do was this:

```
func progressBarButtonFadeOut(){
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
//timeCapDesign is a UIButton

    self.timeCapDesign.alpha = 0

    self.timeCapDesign.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1)

})
}

//Progress Bar Fade In Buttons
func progressBarButtonFadeIn(){
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {

    self.timeCapDesign.alpha = 1

    self.timeCapDesign.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

})
}
```

So ultimately to shrink it i set it to a value of the CGAffineTransformMakeScale really low such as (0.1,0.1) and then animated the alpha to 0 to give the effect that its shrinking to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The scale of "1" is the current size, and if you want to animate it growing, the number should be bigger than 1.

```
func progressBarButtonFadeOut(){
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
//timeCapDesign is a UIButton
    self.timeCapDesign.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)

})
```

}

Comment: How can i animate it to be shrinking?